# split linked list of chars in C

Tags: c, split, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm supposed to write a function called - "disAssemblyList" that gets a linked list of chars(without a dummy element). The function should move a nodes with big letters to "bigLetter" linked list (without a dummy element) , move nodes with small letters to "smallLetter" linked list, nums to "nums" linked list and other chars keep into original list.

**I need to pass by reference the smallLetter, bigLetter and nums linked lists and return the list with other chars.**

I need to scan the original list. The original list can be empty.

for example:

An original linked list:

```
3-> a-> 7-> M-> K-> u-> 5-> #-> &-> P-> %-> A
```

`bigLetter`:

```
M-> K-> P-> A
```

`smallLetter`:

```
a-> u
```

`nums`:

```
3-> 7-> 5
```

other chars (original list after the function runs):

```
#-> &-> %
```

I wrote this code and I cant seem to understand how to make it work. **It does not scan the chars to linked list.**

```
typedef struct chNode
{
    char data;
    struct chNode *next;
}chNode;


chNode * createCharList(char data)
{
    chNode *temp = (chNode*)malloc(sizeof(chNode));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

chNode * addCharToLast(chNode *head, char data)
{
    chNode *p = head;
    chNode *temp = createCharList(data);
    if (head == NULL)
        return temp;
    while (p->next != NULL)
        p = p->next;
    p->next = temp;
    return head;
}

void printf_CharList(chNode *head)
{
    chNode *p = head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d, ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}


chNode* insert_Charlist() // A function that imports numbers into a linked list , till -1
{
    char ch;
    chNode *Head = NULL;
    printf("Enter chars For Linked-List Till 'Enter':\n");
    //5scanf_s("%c", &ch);
    ch = getchar();
    while (ch != "\n")
    {

        Head = addCharToLast(Head, ch); //Makes last number to be First
        //scanf_s("%c", &ch);
        ch = getchar();
    }
    return Head;
}

void add_to_other_list(chNode** head, chNode* p)
{
    static chNode* tail = NULL;

    p->next = NULL;
    if (tail == NULL)
    {
        *head = p;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = p;
    }
    tail = p;
}


chNode* disAssemblyList(chNode* p, chNode **bigLetter, chNode **smallLetter, chNode **nums)
{
    chNode* t = NULL;

    if (p == NULL) return p;          // 0 elements
    if (p->next == NULL) return p;    // 1 element
    if (p->next->next == NULL)          // 2 elements
    {

        if ((p->next->data >= 65) && (p->next->data) <= 90)
        {
            // Move p->next to other list
            add_to_other_list(&(*bigLetter), p->next);
            p->next = NULL;
            return p;
        }
    }

    // Repeat as long as the list has minimum 3 elements
    while (p->next)
    {
        if ((p->next->data >= 65) && (p->next->data) <= 90)
        {
            // Move p-next
            t = p->next;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            add_to_other_list(&(*bigLetter), t);
        }

        if ((p->next->data >= 97) && (p->next->data) <= 122)
        {
            t = p->next;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            add_to_other_list(&(*smallLetter), t);
        }

        if ((p->next->data >= 48) && (p->next->data) <= 57)
        {
            t = p->next;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            add_to_other_list(&(*nums), t);

        }
        p = p->next;
    }

    return p;

}


void main()
{

    chNode *Orignial_list = NULL;
    chNode *bigLetter = NULL;
    chNode *smallLetter = NULL;
    chNode *nums = NULL;
    Orignial_list = insert_Charlist(); // Function that imports a list
    printf("You Entered This linked-list:\n");
    printf_CharList(Orignial_list); //Printing the linked list
    Orignial_list = disAssemblyList(Orignial_list,&bigLetter,&smallLetter,&nums);
    printf("The BigLetter Linked-List is:\n");
    printf_CharList(bigLetter);
    printf_CharList(smallLetter);
    printf_CharList(nums);
    printf_CharList(Orignial_list);
    getch();

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. That is quite a lot of code to go through, so maybe try to cut it down to a 'minimal reproducable example'.

For example try working with only one list for starters.

Also, 'doesn't work' is a terribly generic error description (yet the one we get the most). Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger and following the steps? That may help you a lot trying to figure out where things go south.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Try typing `[mre]` in a comment like that. It is faster for you and more helpful for OP.

Comment: My apologies, @Yunnosch, I am not usually the first to post this, so I was unaware of the shortcut.

Thanks for the heads up. :)

So yes, we will likely require you to post a [mre].

Comment: Please try `while (ch != '\n')` and `printf("%c, ", p->data);`, then we can start discussing the actual algorithm problems.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I wrote that I dont understand why it doesnt scan the linked list.
It run without any errors but I cant scan the chars from user to linked list.

Comment: As Yunnosh already pointed out correctly, your problem may already sit at the 'entry' vector, where you seem to wait for characters 'until enter'.
However at that juncture you are comparing a `char` to a `const char *` which should already be giving you a compilation error.

Comment: @Yunnosch I must use addCharToLast(), createCharList() functions.

Comment: `if (p->next == NULL) return p;` is already wrong, you are supposed to move a single element out of a list too.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium It doesn't give me a compilation error, but also it doesn't scan to the linked list.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  thank you I edited this.

Comment: First step, skip the removing and adding to other lists. Simplify by only scanning the input list and printing "big" or "lil" or "dig" or "oth" for each letter found. Even for that you already have several obstacles in your code. Getting that classification done correctly will give you a foundation for the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not looked through all your code because as I have understood the question is about one function implementation that splits an original list to some other lists.

Though I am sure that there are drawbacks in your code as for example the function `print_CharList` outputs internal codes of characters instead of characters stored in a list themselves.

```
void printf_CharList(chNode *head)
{
    chNode *p = head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d, ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Or the function `add_to_other_list` with a static variable does not make a sense.

Or this condition in beginning of the function `disAssemblyList`

```
if (p->next == NULL) return p;    // 1 elementNevertheless the function
```

also does not make a sense.

Nevertheless the function that splits a list can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct chNode
{
    char data;
    struct chNode *next;
} chNode;

void clear( chNode **head )
{
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        chNode *tmp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

size_t assign( chNode **head, const char *s )
{
    if ( *head ) clear( head );
    
    size_t n = 0;
    
    while ( *s && ( *head = malloc( sizeof( chNode ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        ( *head )->data = *s++;
        ( *head )->next = NULL;
        head = &( *head )->next;
        ++n;
    }
    
    return n;
}

FILE * display( const chNode *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%c -> ", head->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}

chNode * disAssemblyList( chNode *p, 
                          chNode **bigLetter, 
                          chNode **smallLetter, 
                          chNode **nums )
{
    while ( *bigLetter ) bigLetter = &( *bigLetter )->next;
    while ( *smallLetter ) smallLetter = &( *smallLetter )->next;
    while ( *nums ) nums = &( *nums )->next;

    chNode **head = &p;
    
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        if ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )( *head )->data ) )
        {
            *nums = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            ( *nums )->next = NULL;
            nums = &( *nums )->next;
        }
        else if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )( *head )->data ) )
        {
            *bigLetter = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            ( *bigLetter )->next = NULL;
            bigLetter = &( *bigLetter )->next;
        }
        else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )( *head )->data ) )
        {
            *smallLetter = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            ( *smallLetter )->next = NULL;
            smallLetter = &( *smallLetter )->next;
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
    
    return p;
}   

int main(void) 
{
    chNode *head = NULL;
    
    assign( &head, "3a7MKu5#&P%A" );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    chNode *bigLetter = NULL;
    chNode *smallLetter = NULL;
    chNode *nums = NULL;
    
    head = disAssemblyList( head, &bigLetter, &smallLetter, &nums );
    
    fputc( '\n', display( head, stdout ) );
    fputc( '\n', display( bigLetter, stdout ) );
    fputc( '\n', display( smallLetter, stdout ) );
    fputc( '\n', display( nums, stdout ) );
    
    clear( &head );
    clear( &bigLetter );
    clear( &smallLetter );
    clear( &nums );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 -> a -> 7 -> M -> K -> u -> 5 -> # -> & -> P -> % -> A -> null

# -> & -> % -> null
M -> K -> P -> A -> null
a -> u -> null
3 -> 7 -> 5 -> null
```

If you are not allowed to use standard C functions from the header `<ctype.h>` then the while loop in the function `disAssemblyList` can look like

```
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        char c = ( *head )->data;

        if ( '0' <= c && c <= '9' )
        {
            *nums = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            ( *nums )->next = NULL;
            nums = &( *nums )->next;
        }
        else if ( 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z' )
        {
            *bigLetter = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            ( *bigLetter )->next = NULL;
            bigLetter = &( *bigLetter )->next;
        }
        else if ( 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' )
        {
            *smallLetter = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            ( *smallLetter )->next = NULL;
            smallLetter = &( *smallLetter )->next;
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cant use files in this exercise.

Comment: @PashaGrobov And what is the problem? Do not use them. You can use your own function that outputs a list. The demonstrative program is designed to show how the function that splits a list can be implemented.

Comment: It still doesn't solve my problem, the first problem is that I need to scan the original linked list "from the user", and it's doesn't work .

Comment: @PashaGrobov Your question about how to write a function that splits a list. And I showed such a function definition. We do not do here your homework.

Comment: @PashaGrobov If you have some troubles with other function then you should close this your question by selecting the best answer and ask a new question relative to your other problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tiny problems and 2 big ones in your code.

First the tiny problems:

- the code does not contain the required includes:

  ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
  ```

  ok, I shall assume that they are present in your real code (the are, aren't they)
- the code declares a `void main()`. Except for special case (stand alone environment for example to build a kernel) you must use `int main()` and return a value
- you are comparing a `char` and a `char *` in `insert_Charlist` at `while (ch != "\n")`. It should be:

  ```
    while (ch != '\n')
  ```
- you fail to free the allocated memory. Not a big problem because it will be returned to environment at program end, but best practices recommend to always `free` what has been `malloc`-ed.

Now for the serious ones. Both essential functions `add_to_other_list` and `disAssemblyList` and fully broken. It is time to learn how to use a debugger to step through the code and see what happens. Worse, their general logic was broken and I had to re-write them:

```
void add_to_other_list(chNode** head, chNode* p)
{
    static chNode* tail;

    p->next = NULL;
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = p;
    }
    else
    {
        for (tail=*head; tail->next != NULL; tail = tail->next);  //skip to end of list
        tail->next = p;
    }
}

chNode* disAssemblyList(chNode* head, chNode **bigLetter, chNode **smallLetter, chNode **nums)
{
    chNode dummy = {0, head};  // build a dummy node to start one before current head
    chNode *p = &dummy;
    chNode* t;

    // Repeat as long as the list has minimum 1 element to process
    while (p->next)
    {
        if ((p->next->data >= 65) && (p->next->data) <= 90)
        {
            // Move p-next
            t = p->next;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            add_to_other_list(&(*bigLetter), t);
        }

        else if ((p->next->data >= 97) && (p->next->data) <= 122)
        {
            t = p->next;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            add_to_other_list(&(*smallLetter), t);
        }

        else if ((p->next->data >= 48) && (p->next->data) <= 57)
        {
            t = p->next;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            add_to_other_list(&(*nums), t);

        }
        else p = p->next;   // only advance p if p->next has not been moved
    }

    return dummy.next;

}
```